# Django Generic UpdateView and Multitable Inheritance

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Let's say I have the following models:

```
class Post(model):
    ...

class BlogPost(Post):
    ...

class OtherPost(Post):
    ...
```

Assume my url schema to edit a post is something like,

```
/site/post/\d+/edit
```

In other words, I don't have separate url paths for editing `OtherPosts` vs. `BlogPost`.

When using `UpdateView`, I need to set the model -- but of course, the actual model is a subclass of `Post`.

```
class Update(generics.UpdateView):
    model = Post
```

What is the Djangoey/DRY way to handle this?

At the moment, looking over the `UpdateView` code, it looks like I could leave `Update.model` undefined, and override `get_queryset`, which would need to return a query with the right submodel.  I would also need to override `get_form` to return the right form.

I'll post my solution when I get it working, but am looking for possibly better (DRYer) integrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following method is working, which seems fairly minimal.

```
class Update(generic.edit.UpdateView):
    model = Post

    def get_form_class(self):                                                   
      try:                                                                    
          if self.object.blogpost:                                    
              return BlogPostForm
      except Post.DoesNotExist:                                          
          pass                                                                

      try:                                                                    
          if self.object.otherpost:                                     
              return OtherPostForm                                
      except Post.DoesNotExist:                                          
          pass                                                                

      def get_object(self, queryset=None):                                        
          object = super(Update, self).get_object(queryset)                       

          try:                                                                    
              return object.blogpost
          except Post.DoesNotExist:                                          
              pass                          

          try:                                                                    
              return object.otherpost
          except Post.DoesNotExist:                                          
              pass
```

Or, if using a polymorphic mixin like [InheritanceManager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager), then something like this:

```
class Update(generic.edit.UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = {
        BlogPost: BlogPostForm,
        OtherPost: OtherPostForm,
    }

    def get_form_class(self):                                                   
       return self.form_class[self.object.__class__]

   def get_queryset(self):                                                     
      return self.model.objects.select_subclasses()
```